# I can't use Pip to install packages in windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, windows-10

I 'm a Chinese student, When I use pip to update and install, problems like this always occur. My computer is Windows 64.

```
E:\>python -mpip install —upgrade Pip 
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org Packages 'c2 d7 D0f34c60d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843e0211400e55675c. pip-18.1 -PYS.py3 -none -any.whl (1.3MB) 
    -----------------100% 1.3MB 155kB/s
  Installing collected packages: pip
 Found existing installation: pip  10.0.1
  Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
   Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip 

File"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\configparser.py", line 1079, in _read
raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'setup.cfg', line: 1
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n'
```

I googled it and it seems to be a BOM error, but how could I deal with it?

Comment: Please edit the question and copy-paste the error messages instead of posting screenshots

Comment: Never post image of code / errors. Copy and paste (and format) instead please.

Comment: I edited to show code for first one, working on second...

Comment: Well, I'm not typing the second... The first worked in an OCR site, not the second...

Comment: I' sorry...I don't know the rule and how could I edit the question?

Comment: Could be an issue with your python version. What happens if you try `python3` instead of `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

As [Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith) commented correctly, this doesn't solve the real issue, which looks like a byte-sequence error in the `setup.conf` file.

As [kintoki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683367/kintoki) stated, you can try the very popular [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) as your environment, which solves a lot of issues with Python on Windows, but a small caveat is that new version for packages might take some time until you can install them. It is very popular in the data-science community.
I am looking for a more proper answer and will update it here.

---

**Original:**

Pip and Windows don't always work well together. The best way to get around that is to download the packages you want to as pre-compiled binary whl files, directly from [University of Califonia, Irvine python package index for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Then you can install them directly with pip! And don't forget that pip in itself is a package inside pip (inception?)
Assuming you want to install pip 18.1, download [this whl file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) and then run it like so:

```
pip install pip‑18.1‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl
```

This will work the same way for any other python package as well. Just search and download the correct version matching your python version.

Comment: I had done it.But here is still a strange error, it said :
     configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'setup.cfg', line: 1
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n'

Comment: you can also try miniconda, conda works quite well on windows

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the issue, which appears to be a byte order issue in a config file.

Comment: @AdamSmith you are correct. I updated my answer for the time being, until I find a suitable solution.

Comment: @kintoki I credited you in the answer. Thanks for the suggetion.